# How to compare two values and check if they are similar

Tags: php

> **UPDATED EXPLANATION**
>
> I want to check if the alphabetical and numerical characters are contained in the data that the user has provided. Therefore if a users enters LP1 5NQ or LP15NQ and I have an array of data and contained inside of the array is something like this: `array(..., "LP1", ...)` then the script should match the array to **LP1**5NQ or **LP1** 5NQ

So basically what my issue is, is that when I try to check the users input of say LP1 5NQ or something like that I want to check only the start part of their input LP1 but store the LP1 5NQ in their session so that it can be accessed later on. I can already store their input i'm just having trouble with checking the start of the users input.

**PHP**:

```
$op_postcodes = array("DG10","DG3", ......);

function like_in_array( $sNeedle, $aHaystack) {
    foreach($aHaystack as $sKey) {
        if(stripos(strtoupper($sKey), strtoupper($sNeedle)) !== false) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

if(isset($_POST["service_checker"]) && !empty($_POST["service_checker")) {
    $postcode = htmlentities(trim(strtoupper($_POST['postcode'])));
    if(empty($postcode)) {
        $error = "<p class='err_msg'>Your postcode is required so that we can check if our services are available in your area.</p>";
    } else if(like_in_array($postcode, $op_postcodes)) {
        $error = "<p class='pop_up alert success'>Your in! We supply our services to $postcode.</p>";
        $_SESSION['predx_cust_pc_order'] = $postcode;
    } else {
        $error = "<p class='err_msg'>Sorry, we aren't supplying your area just yet.</p>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to my other solution taking into account users that forget the space in the postcode.

According to Wikipedia, the second part of the postcode is always three characters long, so you could use substr to cut off the last three chars and then trim to remove the whitespace which might still be there. Like this:

```
trim(substr("LP1 5NQ", 0, -3));
```

Comment: Thanks - I have a feeling that this will work better. I'll let you know

Comment: the trim does NOTHING, you don't get the 4th character due to the substr

Comment: No problem! Please remember to mark my solution as the correct answer if it works as I'm still fairly new to SO and want the points haha

Comment: @Dagon you are incorrect. The 0, -3 in the substr will cut off the last three characters of the string leaving the first four which includes the whitespace if the user enters a space between the two parts.

Comment: im all backwards again aren't I

Comment: @Dagon I think you are mistakenly thinking I'm using substr to get the first three characters. That is something that could be done, but it wouldn't solve the problem at hand because the first part of a UK postcode can be of a varying length. The second part is always three chars however.

Comment: i just need new glasses brother :-)

Comment: I've found a function that I think is probably really good but I would like a second/third opinion, would that be ok? @Dagon & Ben Wainwright

Comment: @RRAWebteam uh yes ok?

Comment: @BenWainwright I'll add it to my answer as an update

Comment: that matches regardless of position, that may or may not be an issue, i don't know the format of UK postcodes

Comment: @RRAWebteam you shouldn't do that. Stack exchange is meant as a resource for others as well. It's not a wiki; people looking at the question and answer should be able to understand it and they aren't going to be able to understand what the random function is.

Comment: @RRAWebteam well it seems like you are looking for an answer to a different question now so you should create a new question. Also, since I solved the question as it was asked, can you mark mine as the correct answer by clicking the big green tick by my answer please :)

Comment: Ok, and thanks for your help... Could you or I move this over to a chat room

Comment: @RRAWebteam not really. I'm posting this via an app on my phone and I need to sleep.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91992/discussion-between-rra-webteam-and-ben-wainwright).

Answer (score 0):

I would use the 'explode' function like this

```
explode(" ", "LP1 5NQ");
```

This will split the string into an array containing the first part of the postcode and the second part in two different elements. You can then easily access the first element of the array to check it.

Comment: Would you say that this method is the most effective?

Comment: Well that depends on what you mean by effective. It will split the string into two strings and allow the first one to be easily accessed, so yeah I would.

Comment: I understand what it does - but what if a user enters LP15NQ rather than LP1 5NQ? Then wouldn't this method fail?

Comment: I've just added a new solution taking this scenario into account.